# oracle date insert from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I have a Oracle procedure to which I have to pass a datetime value from basic date picker which I assign as bdp1. 
How do I pass this value from VB.net. 
When I pass the date its doest execute the function

```
Public Function GetDate(ByVal strMaterial As String, ByVal ListBox1 As String, ByVal bdp1 As Date) As DataSet

    Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source = ***; User ID = ***; Password = **;"
    Dim sqlConnection As OracleClient.OracleConnection = New OracleClient.OracleConnection(connectionString)


    Dim queryString As String = "select * from abc where tran_dttm <= to_date( ':bdp1','MM-DD-YYYY' ) and tran_dttm > to_date( ':bdp1','MM-DD-YYYY')"


    Dim sqlCommand As OracleClient.OracleCommand = New OracleClient.OracleCommand(queryString, sqlConnection)
    sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0


    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":strMaterial", txtMaterial.Text)
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":ListBox1", ListBox1)
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":bdp1", bdp1)



    Dim dataAdapter As OracleClient.OracleDataAdapter = New OracleClient.OracleDataAdapter(sqlCommand)
    Dim dataSet As DataSet = New DataSet
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet)

    Return dataSet

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Pass it as date, not a string that you then CONVERT to a date in the database. That's crazy talk.

2) If you REALLY want to do that, then you can't quote your parameter: `to_date( ':bdp1','MM-DD-YYYY' )` it's trying to_date the literal string ':bdp1'. Change it to: `to_date( :bdp1,'MM-DD-YYYY' )`

***Edit***

Oops, I misread your code, when I saw your to_date stuff, I assumed you were passing a string. You're actually passing a date, so you shouldn't need to call to_date at all. You should be able to just do this:

```
select * from abc where tran_dttm <= :bdp1 and tran_dttm > :bdp1
```

Again, note that you will not include your parameters in single quotes.

Comment: ok  had pass is as date. should i change  sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":bdp1", bdp1) with sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue to_date( :bdp1,'MM-DD-YYYY' )?

Comment: so just remain this one >> sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":bdp1", bdp1) ?

Comment: I don't think you should have the colon int he parameter name, the colon is only needed in the actual select statement.